# Data counts with groupBy and where

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am going out on a limb here and going to say I reckon this will require some kind of join to do but here is my question anyway.

I have a dataset which is currently being grouped by period and then retrieving the count of the total number of items in those periods.

P1 - 5, P2 - 3, P3 - 9 etc.

I have a filter on the same dataset which I would like to apply, however, this filters out any group by information thats empty (obviously the data doesnt exist) but i would still like to count it as a 0.

Data set 2 example:

P1 - 6, P2 - 0, P3 - 6

This is my current working code for the group by to obtain the count WITHOUT the 0 sized groups:

```
Model::select('period',DB::raw('count(*) as amount'))
    ->groupBy('period')
    ->get();
```

I would like to add something like this:

```
->where('form', 'someformid')
```

My guess which is something like ->leftjoin('samemodelname', id = id) is needed but I am not sure.

I can convert SQL answers if thats easier

EDIT:

Here is the SQL

```
select DISTINCT claims.period, 
(select count(id) FROM claims as c1 where period = claims.period and c1.form=2) as amount
from claims;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply left join and move your where clause inside that join

```
\App\Model::select(['period',DB::raw("count(*) as amount")])
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw("table2 as t2"), function ($join)  {
        $join->on('t2.id', '=', 'model.id');
        $join->on(function ( $query ){
            $query->whereNull('t2.id'); //this will make sure we also count the zero result of left join
            $query->orWhere('t2.form',someformid');
        });

    })
    ->groupBy('period')
    ->get();
```

something like this. Rest you can share SQL query

Comment: Sorry, it appears to show everything and not constrain to the form type: `{"status":"OK","data":[{"period":202004,"amount":1},{"period":202005,"amount":2},{"period":202006,"amount":7},{"period":202007,"amount":1}]}` 07 should read 0

Comment: can you send me your SQL query and i will give you equivalent eloquent query

Comment: if you table2 contain the id and it is the table that contains fewer records  then try this and it will count amount as zero

\App\Model::select(['period',DB::raw("count(t2.id) as amount")])


send your table structure and SQL as well

Comment: I have worked out and added the SQL in my original post now.

Comment: which laravel version you are using. In laravel 6 you can use this reference 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/29567  to generate your query

or you can use this 


$query  =\App\Model::select(['claims.period',DB::raw("( select count(id) FROM claims as c1 where period = claims.period and c1.form=2) as amount " )])
    ->distinct();

Comment: Theres no point looking at raw if i can use `db::select($query)` now is there?